# How to use function callback using laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, widget

I create a simple widget that respond to server and callback function that respond using html. Here my code snippet

```
<div id="example-widget-container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/library.js"></script>
```

and the respond from this

```
? ( {'html': '<strong>Hello World!</strong>' } )
```

this code from pyton and generate html and this is respond

```
hello from the other site: Hello World!
```

Hello World coming from the server that using callback function.

and here my widget.js

```
(function() {

    // Localize jQuery variable
    var jQuery;

    /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src",
            "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
        if (script_tag.readyState) {
          script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
              if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                  scriptLoadHandler();
              }
          };
        } else {
          script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
        }
        // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
    } else {
        // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
        jQuery = window.jQuery;
        main();
    }

    /******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
    function scriptLoadHandler() {
        // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
        // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
        // Call our main function
        main(); 
    }

    /******** Our main function ********/
    function main() { 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

            /******* Load CSS *******/
            var css_link = $("<link>", { 
                rel: "stylesheet", 
                type: "text/css", 
                href: "css/style.css" 
            });
            css_link.appendTo('head');          

            /******* Load HTML *******/
            var jsonp_url = "http://jsonp.local/request-json-array?=callback=?";
            // http://al.smeuh.org/cgi-bin/webwidget_tutorial.py?callback=?

            $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
              $('#example-widget-container').html("hello from the other site: " + data);
            });
        });
    }

    })(); // We call our anonymous function immediately
```

My issue is how to create callback function from json through jsonp using **laravel**. Been try to search google and so far i did't find that good enough for my project.

Thanks to http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/ for great article. Most of the code coming from there.

UPDATED:
I already put my answer, feel free to update with a new answer

Answer (score 0):

By implementing Cross Resource Origin Sharing or known as CORS enable me to use callback function.

Here guide dependencies to implement that enable laravel share its data:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors